# Inserting multiple checkbox values to Postgres in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter, checkbox

I want to make multiple insert checkbox in same ID. I have table like this:

```
id  id_fleet unit_id
1    1       CAO27
2    1       CA098
3    2       CA078
```

in one form submit I select in id_fleet 1 and I check 2 unit_id. I try with my code it only save one check.

this is my code in controller:

```
$fleet = $this->input->post('id_fleet');
            $unit_id = $this->input->post('unit_id');

            $records = array();

            for ($i=0; $i < count($unit_id) ; $i++) { 
                $data = array(
                    'id_fleet' => $fleet,
                    'unit_id' => $unit_id
                );

                array_push($records, $data);
            }

            $query = $this->database_three->query("select
                count(id_fleet_member) as unit from fleet_member 
                where id_fleet = '$fleet'");
            $ans = $query->row();

            if ($ans->unit > 0)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateErrorMessage('Data gagal ditambah'));
                redirect(site_url('fleet_member'));     
            }
            else
            {
                for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($data['unit_id']) ; $i++) { 
                    $query = "insert into fleet_member (id_fleet, unit_id) values ('".$data['id_fleet']."','".$data['unit_id'][$i]."')";
                    pg_query($query);
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', generateSuccessMessage('Data berhasil ditambah'));
                    redirect(site_url('fleet_member'));
                }

            }
```

this is my model:

```
function add_fleet_member($data)
    {
        $this->database_three->insert($this->tbl_fleet_member, $data);
        if ($this->database_three->affected_rows() > 1)
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is in view:

```
<div class="checkbox">
       <?php foreach ($unit_list as $data) :?>
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="unit_id[]" value="<?php echo $data->unit_id ?>"><?php echo $data->unit_id ?>
       </label>
        <?php endforeach?>
</div>
```

can you help me why my code only save one value checkbox?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
        $fleet = $this->input->post('id_fleet');
        $unit_id = $this->input->post('unit_id');
        //all options are as records in this array
        $records = array();
        for($i=0;$i<count($unit_id);$i++)
        {
            //for one record
            $data = array(
                'id_fleet' => $fleet,
                'unit_id' => $unit_id[$i]
            );
            //push one record to other records
            array_push($records,$data);
         }

         $this->load->model("your_model_name");
         //insert multiple records use insert batch active record
         $this->your_model_name->add_fleet_member($records);



        //model function edited
        function add_fleet_member($data=array())
        {
           if($this->database_three->insert_batch($this->tbl_fleet_member, $data))
           {
             return true;
           }
           else
           {
             return false;
           }

         }
```

Comment: can you check my edit in above? i alredy edit with your code, but it same only save one value checkbox

Comment: Sorry for late, yes I will